# Word add-in producing 'Access Denied' error when run on server - fine locally

Tags: ms-office, office-interop

We have a Word addin that works with Excel that is having issues when being run on a remote desktop that's running Server 2012(Multiple users access this server)

Here's a piece of the trace

```
Exception Details:
```

System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Access is denied
   at System.Diagnostics.ProcessManager.OpenProcess(Int32 processId, Int32 access, Boolean throwIfExited)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessHandle(Int32 access, Boolean throwIfExited)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Kill()

When the add-in is run locally, there are no issues at all. We've seen similar issues when working with vmware, citrix, and RDP to servers like this instance.

My question is really what needs to be modified at the server level to make this function properly?  I've found that running Word and Excel as administrator will allow them to properly 'see' each other, but just a normal click will produce the error above.

TIA!

Comment: What line of code fires the exception?

Comment: What is the Word add-in doing? What process is it trying to kill? What is the code which is producing this error? More details please.